# What is the spelling of `~`?

Tags: spelling, reading-aloud, symbols

I searched `~ spelling` and `~ symbol spelling` on Google but found nothing. My dictionary doesn't contain `~` either.

P.S.: is there any online dictionary that can translate symbols? I find I know almost nothing about the symbols. Even in my native language, I say `/\ or something else` tilted stick. I don't know which is slash, and which is backslash.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate) [What is the name for these keys on a computer keyboard?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84624)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, a lot of Americans don't seem to know which one is slash and which one is backslash either!  I hear people get it wrong all the time.  (Slash is **/**.  It's the one that's more natural for a right-handed person to make.)

Comment: If it helps, in the UK at least we call `/` _forward_ slash. and `\ ` _back_ slash. This is easier to remember as you just look for the slash that is leaning forwards or backwards.

Comment: Actually it's very easy to find out by yourself: just _describe_ the character, don't type it: [`curvy dash`](http://google.com/search?q=curvy+dash) was my very first attempt at this, and the first search result gave me the answer.

Comment: To make things even more complicated, there is more than one kind of "slash."  At least 3 different symbols were condensed into the single slash character (back in the days of manual typewriters, where the number of keys had to be limited.)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation). In these days of Unicode and electronic publishing, pedants (like me) will notice incorrect usage. So I applaud the OP's curiosity.

Comment: Also, for symbols, sometimes using "name" instead of "spelling" in your search will give you better results, for example searching for `symbol '~' name`. Actually, tilde seems particularly difficult to search for because it's used in the search engine syntax, but for other symbols my advice might be helpful.

Comment: @Mithril Another resource that might help you is symbolhound.com. It's a search engine that takes symbols into account, although it's not as good as google at finding relevant results. In google, searching for `~ spelling` is the same as just searching for `spelling`

Comment: to search it use a symbol search engine like http://symbolhound.com/, or better use https://unicodelookup.com/#~/1 or any Unicode name searching tool to find its name

Comment: A good way to look up unicode character name without access to the internet is hitting `C-u C-x =` in Emacs text editor. For `~` it says: `name: TILDE` among other things.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe the symbol is known as a *tilde*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde

[The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com) is a good source of information for English punctuation and its usage, including what each symbol is called (though in this case it doesn't mention the *tilde*).

Typing the actual symbol into [Google](https://www.google.com) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) also yields an accurate result.

*[edit]*

If you type a punctuation symbol into Wikipedia (such as tilde, above) it also returns a comprehensive list of other punctuation symbols, spellings, plus links to more detailed information on the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't search the symbol alone on google , this is a very useful information !  And that Punctuation Guide is very helpful too, really help me a lot.

Comment: Given that the question is also tagged reading-aloud it's worth noting that tilde is pronounced "till-da" and not "till-dee"

Comment: What about "squiggle"?

Comment: @Mithril The google search just ignores most punctuation (for example, _ng-trx_ is the same as _ng trx_). As such, it is not a good tool to search about glyphs themselves!

Comment: @Zachiel: If you use the punctuation in a word or sentence, yes, it parses it as part of the word (or search - '-' can be used to instruct the search to ignore certain words for example). However if you type the punctuation mark into Google **on its own**, it does indeed return a [valid response](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=-).

Comment: @BenSutton You might think to write "till-da" because it's the same sound as in "comma", but keep in mind that while that's normally true, "comma" may get a different "a" sound if you emphasise the word. "Tilde" never gets an "a" sound.

Comment: @hvd Good point. So maybe "till-duh"?

Answer (score 7):

The formal name for `~` is **tilde**.

Many programmers call it **twiddle**.

A **slash** or **forward slash** is `/`.  If north is at the top of the page, it points southwest-to-northeast.  It is tilted the same way that most right-handed people slant their writing, so it has a "forward" slant.  Standard American keyboards have `?` as `Shift-/`.

A **whack** or **backslash** is `\`.  If north is at the top of the page, it points northwest-to-southeast.  Standard American keyboards have `|` as `Shift-\`.

See also "[What do programmers call these punctuation marks? (Parentheses, brackets, ticks, etc.)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108169#108173)"

The [ASCII](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html) entry in The New Hacker's Dictionary, [as edited](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/index.html) by Eric S. Raymond, includes English-language computer programming names for many common symbols.

Comment: A little color on why programmers sometimes call a *tilde* a *twiddle*. The `~` symbol is one of several bitwise operators. Programmers use bitwise operators to perform *bit manipulation* or colloquially, *bit twiddling*.

Comment: I'm not disputing programmers call the tilde a "twiddle" somewhere, but where? I've been programming about 15 years and this is the first time I've ever heard that :p. (Also never heard of *bit twiddling*, just *bit manipulation*) (The linked site seems sort of rediculous to me so if there's a joke I'm not getting I apologise!)

Comment: @redstarcoder -- *The New Hacker's Dictionary* contains common programming jargon and in-jokes, especially from the first twenty years of the Arpanet/Internet.  It was heavily influenced by the terms used at Stanford, Berkeley, Carnegie-Mellon, and MIT.  I know that "twiddle" was how MIT hackers referred to "~" during the 1990s.

Comment: I would say the jargon in that dictionary was common *maybe* 27 years ago (based on movies and stereotypes I know), but certainly not today. Thanks for the background though!

Comment: It's still certainly in use, though now as much because it's in the jargon file than the other way around.

Comment: Add mathematicians to the groups that pronounce 'tilde' as 'twiddle.'  It is sometimes used as a relational symbol.  For example, writing A ~ B might formally mean A is similar/congruent/homomorphic to B, but when discussing casually, would be read as A twiddle B.