# What is the difference between these two characters? ` and '

Tags: difference, symbols

I cant figure out why

**`** and **'** are different!

Sometimes I type **'** and my sugggestions for Google say this: **`**

Please help, I am working on a story.

Comment: This isn't about English, it's about computer character sets. ` is a backtick, and not an English punctuation mark at all. ' is an apostrophe, also used as a single opening/closing quote mark.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer characters rather than anything to do with the English language.

Comment: Related questions:  [What is the name for these keys on a computer keyboard?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84624) and [What do programmers call these punctuation marks? (Parentheses, brackets, ticks, etc.)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108169)

Comment: Some people misguidedly use the back tick ` to open a quote and close it with ' because there isn't a fore tick. It looks horrible.